# View PDF file without Acrobat Reader installed

Tags: vb.net, pdf, view

Is it possible to view a pdf file in VB.NET without having Acrobat Reader installed? If yes, how?

Comment: try moonPdfPanel: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/579878/MoonPdfPanel-A-WPF-based-PDF-viewer-control

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself, but [this discussion](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/74198-how-to-view-pdf-file-in-vbnet/) should have many answers for you. There are many ways included in the link to show pdf as an answer to the question: "How can I create my own pdf viewer?". Also, the main problems which you might face during development is handled, too.

The two answers I got from there are:

1- Try this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\test.pdf");
```

2- Using browser widget, which is explained briefly [in this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebBrowserInCSMDB12022005001524AM/WebBrowserInCSMDB.aspx). To do that, you should write this line alongside with others:

```
myWebbrowser.navigate("d:\test.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open it on your default browser, most of browsers have a built-in functionality for pdf, so you wont need the Adobe Reader.

You could even show the pdf in your form with a `WebBrowser` object.

Comment: try `Process.Start("chrome.exe file.pdf")` to open it on a external window.